# How to export SQL Server data to Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sql-server-2008

Currently I'm testing how to export data from SQL Server Management Studio to Excel for an upcoming project.

I looked up online and came upon a code as follows:

```
Function ImportSQLtoRange(ByVal conString As String, ByVal query As String, ByVal target As Range) As Integer

On Error Resume Next

' Object type and CreateObject function are used instead of ADODB.Connection,
' ADODB.Command for late binding without reference to
' Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library

' ADO API Reference
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086(v=VS.85).aspx

' Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim con As Object
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

con.ConnectionString = conString

' Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.CommandText = query
cmd.CommandType = 1         ' adCmdText

' The Open method doesn't actually establish a connection to the server
' until a Recordset is opened on the Connection object
con.Open
cmd.ActiveConnection = con

' Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rst As Object
Set rst = cmd.Execute

If rst Is Nothing Then
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

    ImportSQLtoRange = 1
    Exit Function
End If

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim col As Integer

Set ws = target.Worksheet

' Column Names
For col = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    ws.Cells(target.row, target.Column + col).Value = rst.Fields(col).Name
Next
ws.Range(ws.Cells(target.row, target.Column), ws.Cells(target.row, target.Column + rst.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True

' Data from Recordset
ws.Cells(target.row + 1, target.Column).CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

ImportSQLtoRange = 0

End Function

Sub TestImportUsingADO()

Dim conString As String
conString = "data source = server name; initial catalog = database; uid = name; password = password"

Dim query As String
query = "my query goes here"

Dim target As Range
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(3, 2)

target.CurrentRegion.Clear

Select Case ImportSQLtoRange(conString, query, target)
    Case 1
        MsgBox "Import database data error", vbCritical
    Case Else
End Select

End Sub
```

When I try to use the macro, I receive a message box as set in Case 1 in ImportSQLtoRange. But I'm not sure if that means that the code works and can access the query or this is an error message. If this shows that it does work how do I modify it so that it gives me the table I want based on my query?

**Edit:** Upon following Kazimierz Jawor suggestion, I commented on

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Now I get an error as follows:

[image]

Clicking Debug show the error coming from

```
con.open
```

What does that mean?

Comment: comment `On error resume next` line and you get error exactly in the line where it is produced. Next provide more information about error: error number, error name, in which line it happened

Comment: return a recordeset rather than integer and set your function return to the recordset, rst.

Comment: The error indicates your connectionstring doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the below code

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
```

Below is the example:

```
 Sub GetDataFromADO()
'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=abc;Password=abc;"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "select * from myTable"

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL            

'Copy Data to Excel'
    Do until objMyRecordset.EOF //Test whether the current record is after the last record
          'Your Code
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You can search for the answer [here](https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm)

Comment: Ironically, that was where I got the code from. But I can't figure out which part do I need to change to make it work...

Comment: Did you try the one which i posted in the solution

Comment: The fastest way to import data from recordset to sheet is `Range.CopyFromRecordSet` method.

Comment: @JohnyL : the changes you suggested, Thank you for that. But i have a question `EOF` or the originial `EOR`, what is the difference between them.

Comment: `Range.CopyFromRecordSet` will only work with dynamic range. If the Cell in that Range has to have a particular value, then the method will not be of use as it might give your unwanted result for a blank field

Comment: 1. There's just no such property "EO**R**". 2. I don't understand what do you mean under "will only work with dynamic range". You choose top-left cell where data will be trannsferred. If you need to process each record separately and make some decisions, then you need a loop.

Comment: Lets say there is  Rows x and y and Columns a and b, in the happy scenario where all the values are returned in the sql query. `CopyFromReCordSet` can be used. What will happen if xa and xb values are not present in the database?

Comment: @nishit dey I checked your code and while you did explain properly what to do, I'm not sure what to put in  `your code` area.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way?

```
Sub GetDataFromADO()

    'Declare variables'
        Set objMyconn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rc As Long

    'Open Connection'
        objMyconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog=Your_DB_Name; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

        objMyconn.Open

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyconn
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "select * from [Person].[BusinessEntity] "
        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        objMyCmd.Execute

    'Open Recordset'
        Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyconn
        objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd

    'Copy Data to Excel'
        'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        Application.ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        rc = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rc + 1, 1).Select
        'Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value
        objMyconn.Close

End Sub
```

You can find lots of useful tips about integrating Excel and SQL Server from the link below.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm